# How to receive bluetooth in Desktop folder instead of Download folder?

Tags: bluetooth, downloads, .desktop

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. The files received over Bluetooth in Ubuntu are automatically saved in `Downloads` folder. I wish to receive these files in `Desktop` folder?

Where and how to change these settings?

Comment: `gsettings get org.blueman.transfer shared-path` is this key available?

Comment: Sorry to hitch-hike, I'm also interested in this and not only for ubuntu but also for android. This key is not available on my system (ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: Then blueman is not on your system. but i make this change for my debian.I'll try it in my lubuntu.